# Install CA on iOS simulator Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, ca, truststore

I've got a CA certificate file. I'd like to install it on every iOS simulator available as part of a script. I've had a look around and used both https://github.com/ADVTOOLS/ADVTrustStore and https://github.com/yageek/iostrust but neither of them successfully install the certificate (they appear to install it successfully, but navigating to Settings in the simulator doesn't show any profiles installed). I am trying to install them on iOS 9.1 and iOS 8.4.

I can install the CA certificate by dragging and dropping it into the simulator, but I would like to find a way to do this automatically, as part of a set-up script. Has anyone had any success doing this?

Comment: Could you fill a ticket on iostrust tracker with some informations ?

Comment: I checkout tonight. The process seems to be more complex than just inserting a record inside a sqlite database. A lot of others files and plist are create within the documents directory :( Will need a lot of work.

Comment: I try a new approach. Take a look at https://github.com/yageek/SimCert.